# Multiple Entry Brazilian Tourist Visa for Indian Citizen

Tags: indian-citizens, brazil, multiple-entry, tourist-visas

I had been living in Brazil last year on VITEM IV Multiple Entry Student Visa which has expired as of date. I will be traveling and working in Colombia this year, but have a few friends whom I would like to visit Brazil during my vacations for the World Cup, Christmas and the Carnival.

I'm an Indian Citizen and would like to know if I can get a long term multiple entry tourist visa, such as the American Citizens which is valid for 10 years?

Also what all documents do I need to show in case I am valid for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Get a VITUR Visa which costs Rs. 1600 and is valid for a maximum of 5 years. Write a letter to them explaining your situation and you'll be good to go!

**A list of documents and important information is also given on the [New Delhi Embassy website](http://novadelhi.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/important_information.xml).**

As you might have already guessed you're gonna need a Tourist Visa of the VITUR Category. The price of this Visa is [Rs. 1600](http://novadelhi.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/visa_fees.xml) (Because you're an Indian Citizen). I'm going to go ahead and assume that you and your friends will be applying for the visa in India so it's payable in Rupees.

The visa is usually multiple entry and each entry allows you a maximum of 90 days up to a total of 180 days in a single year. The visa *may* be valid for a maximum of up to 5 years but this is entirely up to the discretion of the embassy issuing the visa. The form on **[VisaHQ Passport services](http://brazil.visahq.com/requirements/India/resident-United_States/)** which can be used to apply for the visa clearly states **up to 1825 days**.

You can write a letter to the embassy explaining why you would like a long term tourist visa. Also, I believe in some cases the embassy decides what kind of visa to give you. The New Delhi site does not mention this *but* the [New York site](http://novayork.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/tourism_visa.xml) does. An in-depth but old example of the same is given on the [Consulate General of Chicago](http://www.brazilconsulatechicago.org/en-5-0-0.html?topic=Visas) website.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Brazil#Tourist_visa) as well as the [Other Visas Section of the New Delhi](http://novadelhi.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/other_visas.xml) site will also tell you that the visa is valid from the first entry into the country until the expiry of the visa.

Comment: I don't know anything about these visas, but you just told the other poster that his wasn't relevant, but he also suggested a VITUR in the first line of his answer?

Comment: @MarkMayo VITUR is absolutely correct. The rest of the information IMHO is not valid to the OP.

Comment: Ah well, I wasn't sure - you didn't say that in your comment, but downvoted the answer which contained some of the same stuff as yours, so I wanted to check.

Comment: @MarkMayo That's fair Yeah! :D

Comment: @Aditya Somani: I am currently in Bogota, Colombia, can I apply for a visa from here?

Comment: @killswitch Of course. As long as you are outside Brazil you can apply for it without any problems.